# Connected components of $X \times Y$

Tags: general-topology

For $X$ and $Y$ topologicl spaces, what are the connected components of $X\times Y$?

I showed that if $C$ and $K$ are connected components of $X$ and $Y$ resp, then $C \times K$ is connected, but didnt show they are maximal.

And I'm not sure how to show the reverse

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof product of components in factors is a component in product topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1300572/proof-product-of-components-in-factors-is-a-component-in-product-topology) See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782999/a-times-b-connected-component-implies-a-b-connect-components